# Finding a repeated pattern and doing something with the match

Tags: java, regex

I have several implementations of finding a repeated pattern and acting on the matching input if it is found.

So I want to find this `<pattern><pattern><pattern>...` or, using regular expression-like syntax: `<pattern>*` without any additional input before or after the pattern.

---

The additional requirements I've put to myself are:

1. code captures meaning well;
2. regular expression simply captures pattern (no spurious characters
   including `^` or `$`);
3. each character evaluated only once by regular expression;
4. matching will stop once a non-pattern is found (disqualifies `find()`
   method);
5. single throws statement if string does not consist of repeated
   pattern;
6. minimum number of branches, minimum of local variables;

---

Below is the fourth try which I think is as close to optimal as I can get:

```
/**
 * Goal: Match input against "<pattern>*" doing stuff with each match.
 * No spurious characters may be present at the head or tail of the input.
 * 
 * Requirements:
 * <nl>
 * <li>code captures meaning well</li>
 * <li>regular expression simply captures pattern (no spurious characters
 * including ^ or $)</li>
 * <li>each character evaluated only once by regular expression</li>
 * <li>matching will stop once a non-pattern is found (disqualifies find()
 * method)</li>
 * <li>single throws statement if string does not consist of repeated
 * pattern</li>
 * <li>minimum number of branches, minimum of local variables</li>
 * </nl>
 * 
 * @param hex
 *            the hexadecimal input
 * @return the byte array containing the hexadecimal match
 */
private static byte[] fromHex4(final String hex) {
    // setup array
    final byte[] data = new byte[hex.length() / 2];

    final Pattern hexDigits = Pattern.compile("\\p{XDigit}{2}");
    final Matcher m = hexDigits.matcher(hex);
    // optimization, m.regionEnd() could also be hex.length() I suppose
    final int end = m.regionEnd();
    // m.lookingAt() allows input to be present *after match*
    while (m.lookingAt()) {
        // do stuff with the match
        data[m.start() / 2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(m.group(), 16);
        // start next lookingAt at end of last match
        m.region(m.end(), end);
    }
    // m.requireEnd() cannot be used here, the last find may not have
    // resulted in a match
    if (m.regionStart() != end) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No hexadecimal encoded byte present at character index " + m.regionStart());
    }
    return data;
}
```

The hexadecimal parsing is only used as an example. I *know* how to optimize hexadecimal parsing (up to requiring a single `for` loop and a single `if` statement if need arises). It isn't a given that the pattern always needs to capture a constant amount of characters.

---

Notes:

- I've not used a constant value for the `Pattern` to aid readability for code review;
- in case you're unfamiliar with the Java regexp engine: `\\p{XDigit}` matches a single hexadecimal character;

---

I've ended up using the relatively unfamiliar [`lookingAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--), any remarks on this choice are welcome (readability, compatibility with other regex engines).